# How to make a loading bar on single table when they make a request data?

Tags: javascript, mysql

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

          setInterval(function () {
                    $('#RoomBlock').children('div').each(function () {
                        ShowRoom($(this).attr('id'));
                    });
                }, 10000);
          
          function ShowRoom(id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/localhost/GetData/" + id
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response != null) {
                        $('#' + id).empty();
                        $('#' + id).append(response);

                    } else {
                        alert("null");
                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("error!");
                }
         });
})
```

i have 5 table and they always fetch data from server for several time, success times for every table is different, i want to put some loading bar on every table when they make a request. is there any way to do that with javascript ?
the one that make confuse is how to know that the first table is make a request and still while the other one was done.

Comment: could you please add some code to show how you're doing the fetch calls, to get some context about your problem.

Comment: ok, i put a javascript that i use to fetch data

Comment: In ajax you can use `aync: false` to make sure the current call always completes before another one is fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {

          setInterval(function () {
                    $('#RoomBlock').children('div').each(function () {
                        ShowRoom($(this).attr('id'));
                    });
                }, 10000);

          function ShowRoom(id) {
            /* Add some loader here (bar or image)*/
            var loaderHtml = "<div id='loader_'+id>_____Add your loader code here_____</div>";
            $('#' + id).append(loaderHtml);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: "/localhost/GetData/" + id
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response != null) {
                        $('#' + id).empty();
                        $('#loader_'+ id).remove();
                        $('#' + id).append(response);

                    } else {
                        alert("null");
                        $('#loader_'+ id).remove();
                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("error!");
                }
         });
})
```